# Returning promises to indicate asynchronous function completion

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

I am writing some Node JS code which is essentially some schedule driven logic.

The start times for when a set of functions should be dispatched are defined in a database somewhere, and the main Node JS function is responsible for calling for the execution of these functions when the start time is reached.

In the simplest case, there is a process which is scheduled to run at `18:00` each day.

I think that I can use promises in a sensible way to asynchronously run these tasks, but I am not quite sure how to do it.

Here's some initial ideas. Starting off with some kind of function which is responsible for dispatching all the functions which can be scheduled.

```
function dispatcher(taskType) {
    let returnPromise = new Promise();

    if(taskType === 'task1') {
        function1(returnPromise);
    }
    else if(taskType === 'task2') {
        function2(returnPromise);
    }
    else if(taskType === 'task3') {
        function3(returnPromise);
    }
}
```

The main driver function would be something like this

```
function main() {
    
    const [waitTime, taskType] = getNextTask();
    let runningTasks = [];

    if(waitTime > 120) { // 2 minutes
        sleep(60 * 1000); // some function to sleep for 1 minute
    }
    else {
        sleep(waitTime * 1000); // Wait until time to start task
        const returnedPromise = dispatcher(taskType);
        runningTasks.push(returnedPromise);
    }

    // TODO: somehow inspect the array `runningTasks` and determine
    // for each element, has the promise resolved or rejected?
    
}
```

I am not quite sure how I would write the actual task functions.

```
function1(promise) {
    ok = doSomeLogic();

    if(ok) {
        promise.resolve(); // ?
    }
    else {
        promise.reject(); // ?
        // or maybe
        throw 'some error'; // ?
    }

    // return ?
}
```

This is really an initial sketch of an idea. Can anyone point me in the right direction? I am relatively confident at using Promise objects in C++, but in JS they don't quite work as I would expect. (At least as far as I can tell from reading the documentation. Possibly I misunderstand.)

If it was not clear from the code sketches, the objective is to:

- Dispatch asynchronous tasks (functions)
- At a later date check if those tasks have finished (which tasks of a set of dispatched asynchronous tasks have finished, did they finish with success or failure condition, and what data is returned if any)
- Main thread will sleep periodically when no new tasks are due for dispatch
- It will periodically check to see if tasks finished running and their exit condition and returned data, if any

I hope that makes sense? If not please ask further questions and I will try to answer.

Comment: For starters, passing an empty Promise to the task methods so that they can resolve it does not really make sense. Simply `return function1();`, and inside `function1`, return a Promise

Comment: Just created a rough sketch for you may be it helps - https://replit.com/join/gzkjqprxis-shubhamdixit863

Comment: @ShubhamDixit Where in that sketch are tasks started? I can see something which looks like logic to re-run failed tasks, but not start new ones?

Comment: *"inspect the array `runningTasks` and determine for each element, has the promise resolved or rejected?"*: this polling is atypical when working with promises, where the principle is "don't call us, we'll call you". So you should only have to "listen" to promises with `then` callbacks.

Comment: Why not create a promise for each function (task) which creates first creates a timeout-promise and when it expires chains the promise returned by function. This gives you a promise that remains pending during the waiting time and during the subsequent execution of the asynchronous function, and finally resolves when all that is done. Each of these task promises can be "listened" to via their `then` callbacks.

Comment: @trincot I understand some of your suggestion, but not all of it... Can you elaborate a bit further? In particular, how would I call `then()` for an arbitary number (essentialy infinite number) of tasks, which can be dispatched at arbitrary times.

Comment: At each time you add a task, you chain a `then()` to it? Maybe you should tell us what exactly you want to do when 1 out of 1000 other promises resolves?

Comment: ...and whatever that is, can be done in that `then` callback. The whole idea of a main thread that checks at set intervals to see if anything resolved is an antipattern for promises. Promises have already the capability to send you a notification, so you should not have to check at intervals, but just react when getting called (via a `then` callback).

Comment: I guess what I probably want to do is to update something in a database to keep a record of whether the exit was a success or failure state. At least as a minimal starting point?

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant you are doing `queuing`, does it better if you use `message broker` like `rabbitMQ, kafka, etc`? with them you only need to setup a `worker` service, and boom, done.

Comment: @TobokSitanggang Those options probably seem a bit overkill? It's not so much that I am queueing up messages to be processed, more that there is a schedule for when some actions can be performed and what I am writing right now is a driver function to call the relevant function at the relevant time defined by the schedule. The promise part is just to track whether those functions actually complete, when they complete and what data, if any is returned. It doesn't seem like something Kafka is really suited for. Not sure about rabbitMQ, but again I suspect probably no?

Comment: i dont think its overkill, rabbitMQ would be a good choice because its opensource. the thing is, how would you make the `schema` within the `message` so the worker service can works as expected.  as you mention about run `periodically`, you could use expiry time in the message, if you want to know the progress, you can do it in the `worker` service that you are going to build. if you want to run specific task and/or run in specific time , put the task name and the time to run in the message.

Comment: Why re-invent any of the myriad mechanisms for task scheduling?

Comment: @DaveNewton such as?

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant If you search for "nodejs task scheduling" you'll find a quantity of options including node-y ones (node-cron, node-schedule, etc), regular cron jobs, ones that rely on external queues/brokers (Redis, RabbitMQ, ...), you name it. What makes the "most sense" depends on your needs. It rarely makes sense to roll your own.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no need to have a main thread the monitors whether some promises have resolved or not. Promises were designed to make a callback when they resolve, so there should be no need to poll the state of a promise.

To make this more concrete, let's take the example where we have three types of asynchronous tasks:

- An HTTP request
- A random delay
- An CSS animation

Each of these can be accompanied by an initial delay that can be configured via user input.

Each task (including the delay) can be initiated by the user, either separately, or all together.

Each initiated task will return a promise that will only resolve when the task has finished. At that time any `then` listeners will be called, which should be all that  a main program would need, as anything can be done in those callbacks.

Here is a demo, where you can press buttons to start tasks, and where one function is called whenever a task resolves:

```js
// Utility function: a promise-based version of setTimeout
const delay = (ms) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

// Definition of the tasks
const tasks = {
    task1: function () {
        // Fetch an object from a remote resource
        return fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
                    .then(response => response.json());
    },
    task2: function () {
        // Wait for some random time
        return delay(Math.random() * 1000 + 1000).then(() => "timer expired");
    },
    task3: function () {
        // Run an animation on the current HTML page
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            requestAnimationFrame(() => { // Wait for page to have refreshed before starting animation
                requestAnimationFrame(() => {
                    document.addEventListener("transitionend", () => {
                        resolve("object moved");
                        document.querySelector("div").style.marginLeft = 0;
                    }, { once: true });
                    document.querySelector("div").style.marginLeft = "50px";
                });
            });
        });
    }
}

// Function to perform a given task including the preliminary delay
async function performTask(task, afterDelay) {
    await delay(afterDelay);
    return tasks[task]();
}

// I/O handling:

// Event handlers for the user to control when a task should start
const delayInputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button.task");
const outputs = document.querySelectorAll("td:last-child");

// This function gets called each time a promise resolves:
//    Here you do whatever you need to do to keep track of promise states
function listener(i, response) {
    outputs[i].textContent = JSON.stringify(response);
    outputs[i].style.backgroundColor = "";
}

buttons.forEach((button, i) => {
    button.addEventListener("click", () => {
        // Give a visual indication that this task starts
        outputs[i].innerHTML = "starting (delay + task)...";
        outputs[i].style.backgroundColor = "orange";
        // Start the task including the preliminary delay... and await (non blocking):
        performTask(button.dataset.task, +delayInputs[i].value)
              .then(response => listener(i, response));
    });
});
```

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse; margin: 10px 0 10px 0 }
table td { border: 1px solid; text-align: center; margin: 5px }
td:last-child { width: 28em }
div.anim { transition: margin-left 4s; border: 1px solid; background: silver; display: inline-block;  }
input { width: 5em }
```

```html
<table>
<tr><th>Delay</th><th>Launch</th><th>Message</th></tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="number" value="1000"></td>
    <td><button class="task" data-task="task1">Task 1 (Fetch)</button></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="number" value="500"></td>
    <td><button class="task" data-task="task2">Task 2 (Timeout)</button></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="number" value="200"></td>
    <td><button class="task" data-task="task3">Task 3 (Animation)</button></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
</table>

<br><br>
<div class="anim">(animation)</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I think something like this would work. (Will investigate in more detail next time I have time to work on this.) Just to point out having a function `listener` which takes an argument `i` is a bit of a horrendous anti-pattern, given that for each possible value of `i` we would need a seperate `if` block to handle the logic... But this could be avoided by removing the `buttons.forEach` loop and just calling each promise/function dispatch explicitly by itself. (Hope that makes sense?)

Comment: This is just an example. Here each task happens to correspond to a row in the table, but it can be anything, even the function object of the task... It just needs to be some *handle* with which you can **avoid** multiple `if` statements. There seems no limiting factor here. Yes, you can do this without the loop, but at the cost of code repetition, which I wanted to avoid. It all depends on your actual scenario... My main point here is to show that you don't need the idea of a main thread that polls at regular intervals what the state of the task execution is.